# What is the best ways to build a string via a function in php?

Tags: php, html, function, functional-programming

So maybe I'm just having a brain hiccup, idk. But it seems like this should work but it doesn't.

### The Intent

Build a string throughout a page for use later on in the app page.

### The Question

How do we store a string in a way that we can add to it with a function several times before using the resulting value of the string? Is there a better way to do this with a function than to use a variable?

### A Non-Working Example

```
<?php
$testNG = "";
function testNG($tng){
  $testNG .= $tng;
  return $testNG;
}
testNG("hello!!");
?>
<h2><?= $testNG; ?></h2>
```

As always, thank you all for contributing to making the online world a much more efficient place!

### Edit

An example purpose for this would be to allow Javascript to be aggregated into a variable so that it can be created near the elements it effects, then placed in a  section before the `</body>`

```
<div id="rating"></div>
<?php testNG("$('#rating').rating();"); ?>
<p>blah blah</p>
...

...
</footer>
<?php
if($testNG != ""): ?>
<script>
<?= $testNG; ?>
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need an object, or an array, rather than adding to a string. Adding to a string makes code hard, because as soon as you want to do something specific you have to put your code in the middle, or wherever it needs to be to fit your result in the string. that's a very bad smell

Comment: If you explain your actual reason and code rather than a fake one where it makes no sense to do it, perhaps we can advise on a better way, or at least the way you want. As it is, you've already made a function that does what you want :)

Comment: You'd think it does what I want, but on the test file, the variable doesn't get appended to. It merely holds the initial value before the function. This is why I feel like I'm having a brainfart.

Comment: updated with an example usage

Comment: Ah I see now you say that, `$testNG` is not defined within the scope of the function, only outside of it. You can either make a global var in the function (not nice), pass by reference, pass another param in - so the var you are appending to and the value to append - OR just append the value to the var without a function. I think the function is overkill. eg `$theVar  = ''; $theVar .= 'my new value'; $theVar .= 'another thing';`

Comment: I personally am trying to allow the value to be placed within a field, then passed through a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is to declare `$testNG` as `static` within your function rather than using a global variable. From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static):

> A static variable exists only in a local function scope, but it does not lose its value when program execution leaves this scope.

So each time you call the function it will add the input to whatever's already there.

```
<?php

function testNG($tng = '') {
    static $testNG = '';
    return $testNG .= $tng;
}

testNG("hello!!");
testNG(" world!!");
testNG(" etc.");
?>
<h2><?= testNG(); ?></h2>
```

[Demo at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/GPqsf)

Comment: Thanks, does just what I personally need it to do. However, if the community votes another answer higher that does a more preferred way I will make that the accepted answer. This is definitely what I was looking for, though!

Comment: Note that there's no way to reset this back to the initial empty string. You can't do this more than once in the program. Maybe when it's called without an argument you could clear the variable while returning its value.

Comment: I removed my comment, you were right :) Still not a nice way to go about this though "IMO". I have to have a good luck at that function to see what it's doing, and it's still adding data to a single var in order of whenever the function is called. There are more clear and elegant ways to do this, again imo :)

Comment: @James I respect your opinion. Honestly, I wouldn't find a function like this particularly useful. It is rather limited due to its linearity, although some improvements could probably be made as Barmar suggested. I really just wanted to point out another potentially viable way to avoid using a global.

Comment: Yeah no worries just discussing it. I upvoted. It does solve this question pretty well :)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, with a little introduction to OOP, might be something like:

```
<?php

 class overSimplifiedJSViewHelper 
 {

     protected $_strOut;

     public function append($strIn)
     {
         $this->_strOut = $this->strOut . $strIn;
     }

     public function clear()
     {
         $this->_strOut = '';
     }

     public function getStrOut()
     {
         return $this->_strOut;
     }
 }


 $jsOut = new overSimplifiedJSViewHelper;

 $jsOut->append("$('#rating').rating();");
 $jsOut->append("alert('foo)");

 echo $jsOut->getStrOut();
```

I feel like the crux of your question is really about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

OP might also want to look at PHP's [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

P.S. maybe look at design patterns like the registry pattern as you start to learn more about scope and how to maintain sanity, not placing everything in the global space... we remember "register globals"...
Examining other peoples code, specifically PHP frameworks is a great way to learn!

Comment: I definitely appreciate the tips. I'm going to play around with your example for sure. A class makes the most sense, as it can be used multiple times for different purposes.

Comment: `_$strOut` should probably be `$_strOut`, however [PSR2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) advice against such prefixing.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Using a string will be difficult when you adding more content afterwards. Instead, use an array or object.

You can define an array() or object at the top of your page like this:

```
$testNG = array();
```

Then you can add values to your array wherever you want:

```
$testNG[] = $tng; or
$testNG['key'] = $tng;
```

Otherwise, if you want to keep using your string, add the variable as global in your function:

```
function testNG($tng){
   global $testNG;

   $testNG .= $tng;
   return $testNG;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have numerous answers which solve your exact requirements perfectly. However just *a look from another viewpoint*:

You asked for a function, and to do that you can add another param, pass by reference, use a global variable, or use a static variable. Globals are bad, this is known. But are the other ways really necessary? I won't go into adding another param or pass by reference as they're the same overkill I feel is present in using static, so will use that as an example for all function approaches:

```
function appendValueToVar($newValue = '')
{
    static $theValue = '';

    return $theValue .= $newValue;
}

appendValueToVar('value1');
// More code
appendValueToVar(' - value2');
// More code

echo appendValueToVar();
```

The problem with this approach is you have a function that isn't obvious what it does at first glance. Also, you call the same function to append a value to the static var as well as retrieve it. This is like having a getter and setter in one, which is a bit of a smell, and violates SRP (and other principles).

You can see that with the name, I called it `appendValueToVar`, but should I have called it `getValueFromVar`? Something else? It doesn't really know what it is trying to be.

The main point though, principles etc aside, is how does this save any time or effort over just simply appending to the variable, which is simple and intent is obvious?

```
$theValue = '';
// More code
$theValue .= 'value1';
// More code
$theValue .= 'value2';
// More code
echo $theValue;
```

To me using a function for this is overkill, introduces a large layer of complexity and potential confusion to visual and intent, is more to maintain, etc.

If you want to make your code better, that's great, but a (my opinion..) convoluted function for little gain with a lot of complexity is not really the best way to go about it. It's not really any improvement.

Write a very simple class that gets and sets the data to an object. It's not hard for what you want:

```
class YourValue
{
    private $value = '';

    public function setValue($newValue)
    {
        $this->value .= $newValue;
    }

    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}


$yourValue = new YourValue;
$yourValue->setValue('value1');
//More code
$yourValue->setValue(' - value2');
//More code
echo $yourValue->getValue();
```

*However*, as elegant, clean, manageable, and re-usable as this is, it's also entirely overkill for what you want. Unless your value is something like (eg) an important incrementing amount like someone's shopping cart total (or whatever).

Hope that helps :)